# Attribute already defined with incompatible format (Original attribute defined here)

Tags: android, gradle, android-appcompat, android-support-design

Can't build project after adding

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
```

Keeps giving the following errors:

[image]

Seems like, the problem is with supporting vector drawables. Somewhere some attributes are added twice.

For instance, built values.xml file contains:

```
<declare-styleable name="AppBarLayout_LayoutParams"><attr name="layout_scrollFlags"><flag name="scroll" value="0x1"/><flag name="exitUntilCollapsed" value="0x2"/><flag name="enterAlways" value="0x4"/><flag name="enterAlwaysCollapsed" value="0x8"/></attr><attr format="reference" name="layout_scrollInterpolator"/></declare-styleable>
```

and

```
<declare-styleable name="AppBarLayout_Layout"><attr name="layout_scrollFlags">
        <flag name="scroll" value="0x1"/>
        <flag name="exitUntilCollapsed" value="0x2"/>
        <flag name="enterAlways" value="0x4"/> 
        <flag name="enterAlwaysCollapsed" value="0x8"/>
        <flag name="snap" value="0x10"/>
```

I have this added to gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0' + '@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0' + '@aar'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
```

Comment: try to remove @aar

Comment: Can't see any connection, but I still removed and checked. That is not the problem

Comment: put your layout.xml in which you receive this error

Comment: Is your issue resolved ? i am having the same issue can you share how did you solved this ?

Comment: I changed support library to an older version (all of them, and it worked). Recently changed to the newer version and it works without problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem appears when different versions of the same library present within the application. In this case, different versions of support library.

If you don't see them in your gradle file, then they are probably added as dependencies. Run the following in terminal, to see the dependencies for each library:

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

Then, find the libraries that use old versions of appcompat and update / remove, whatever suits you.

Answer (score 1):

You have the same property name as the other controls, and modify the name of the property of your custom control

```
<declare-styleable name="MyBgView">
        <attr name="textString" format="string" />
        <attr name="textSizes" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="triangleSize" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="backgrounds" format="color" />
        <attr name="textColors" format="color" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Android sdk is not avoid to extended attributes.Use up parent namespace

```
<declare-styleable name="AppBarLayout_Layout" parent="AppBarLayout_LayoutParams">
    <attr name="layout_scrollFlags">
</declare-styleable>
```